# Mongodb query fails with FilterDefinition in a Collection using c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to move this "simple" query from MongoDB Console to my C# Code.

This is the query:

```
db.getCollection('Entity').find({ Keywords : { $regex : /ABC/ } })
```

This query returns all Entities that have a keyword that contains 'ABC' in the array of keyowords.

When I try to do that in C# using the MongoDB C# Driver, I code that:

```
FilterDefinition<Entity> filterDefinition = "{ Keywords : { $regex : /ABC/ } }";
var data= await _repository.Collection.Find(filterDefinition).ToListAsync();
```

But I have an error:

> FormatException: JSON reader expected a string but found '/ABC/'.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an expression that contains a Regex like this

```
var regex = new Regex("ABC");
return collection.Find(e => regex.IsMatch(e.Keywords)).ToListAsync();
```

If you want to create a `FilterDefinition` use the builder

```
var filter = Builders<Entity>.Filter.Regex("keywords", new BsonRegularExpression("ABC"));
return collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

If you want to find matches in an array use an expression like

```
return collection.Find(e => e.Keywords.Any(k => regex.IsMatch(k)).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: @chemitaxis I added an example for an array.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine... but why is not working my solution? I can see that the filter is the same.

Comment: It's not necessary the second part: var filter = Builders<Entity>.Filter.Regex("Keywords", new BsonRegularExpression("/" + query + "/")); That works perfectly.

Comment: @chemitaxis I think because the `FilterDefinition` string conversion expects JSON, and JSON does not have regex literals

Comment: Please, edit your answer with my comment and I check like OK :)

Comment: I added `"ABC"` as parameter. I'm sure you don't need slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Matches method in the csharp driver? You can use the Mongo query builders to construct your query to run against your collection.

e.g.

```
var search = "ABC";    
Query<Entity>.Matches(t => t.Keywords, new BsonRegularExpression(string.Format("/{0}/i", Regex.Escape(search))));
```

The returning IMongoQuery can then be used to query your collection along with other queries.